# How to get first derivation of equation in matlab

Tags: matlab

if i have function f(x,y,z), how to get first derivation of my function in matlab.

f'=df(x,y,z)/d(x,y)

Is it true if I use this method f' = diff(f,x) + diff(f,y) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question; so long as the `f(x,y,z)` function outputs an M x N vector/matrix, you can use the `diff` function to obtain the numerical solution to derivative (as opposed to the analytical solution). The number of variables used to create the matrix isn't important.

Do note that if you're working on a matrix, you will have to consider the direction of the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

If `f(x,y,z)` allows you to create a 2D array such that an element `i,j` of the array is the value of `z` corresponding to a coordinate pair `xi,yj`, then yes, you can use `diff` for the numeric difference.

Note that in your case, you need to specify three inputs to [DIFF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/diff.html), as the second input is the order of the difference, not the dimension. Also, `diff` gives you the difference. To get the correct value of the derivative, you need to divide by the step size in your `x` and `y` value as well (unless the coordinates increment by 1).